# "There is no Row at position 0"

Tags: vb.net

I would like to select the `slot` that value `1-53`, then I need to select at above row for `lot` `id`.
The string that I need is the `lot id` that have `1-53` slots.
But apparently it gives me that error.

```
Dim selectSlots As String = " select distinct time,process,oven ,line, substring (process,8,3) as process1 from table5 Where  process like '%slots =%' and oven ='15'  order by oven ,line"

Dim AdpterselectSlots As New SqlDataAdapter(selectSlots, con1)
Dim DtselectSlots As New DataTable()
AdpterselectSlots.Fill(DtselectSlots)

Dim sortSLots = DtselectSlots.Rows.Count
Dim count = 0

For x As Integer = 0 To sortSLots - 1

    If DtselectSlots.Rows(x).Item("process1") >= 1 And DtselectSlots.Rows(x).Item("process1") <= 53 Then

        Dim line = DtselectSlots.Rows(x).Item("line") - 1
        Dim selectLots As String = "select distinct time,process,oven ,line, substring (process,48,23) as process1 from table5 Where  process like '%''QCheck'' Button%' and oven ='15' and line = '" & line & "'  "
        Dim Adpterselectlots As New SqlDataAdapter(selectLots, con1)
        Dim Dtselectlots As New DataTable()
        Adpterselectlots.Fill(Dtselectlots)
        Dim lotID = Dtselectlots.Rows(0).Item("process1")
        Dim lotID1 = lotID.Trim()

        Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand("insert into chamber1([lotnumber] ,[Oven],[line]) values ( @line , @line1,@line2 )", con1)
        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@line", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = lotID1
        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@line1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "15"
        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@line2", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = line
        con1.Open()
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con1.Close()
    End If
Next
```

Comment: SQL injection ahoy!

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error "there is no row at position 0" because your datatable doesn't have any rows in it, so asking for `DtselectSlots.Rows(0)`, which you do on your first iteration of the loop (where `x=0`), is crashing out

Add some checking to ensure there are at least `sortSlots` number of rows in your table. If sortSlots is 100, your loop will run from 0 to 99. You will need 100 rows in your table to avoid a crash of "there is no row at position XX"

Comment: i did, the problem is when it comes to 0 row select in query thats why im getting the error

Comment: "I did" - You can't possibly have: If you had added a `If DtselectSlots.Rows.Count > 0 Then` before you tried to access the row at position 0 there is no way your code would have thrown this error. Add some checking, like I say.